# The use of "that" and "it" in context

Tags: pronouns

Lets say I am at a table with my friend across from me and he takes out his phone and puts it on the table. And the phone is the only phone on the table. How do I refer to it: with *it* or *that*? For example:

> Is **it** your phone?
>
> Is **that** your phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary definition of "it" is:

> used to refer to a thing previously mentioned or easily identified.

So, in asking whether to use "it" you need to ask - has the phone been identified?

You could begin by asking "Is *that* your phone?", then it is clear you are talking about that specific phone. Follow-up questions could then use "it", for example, "how long have you had *it*?"

There may be ways you could skip straight to "it" *indirectly*, or even *non-verbally*. You could nod at the phone and ask "is it yours?", or if either you or the other party referred to the phone in some way without using *this* or *that*, for example:

> Friend: I've got something to show you. [draws phone out of pocket]
>   You: Wow! Is *it* yours?

Comment: Let's say. My friend I have a phone in our pokets. And one of the phones has started ringing, but I don't know whose. Do I say "is it yours" or "is that yours"?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Based on the reasoning in my answer, what do you think? Has the phone been clearly identified in an indirect or non-verbal way? Have both of you definitely heard it?

Comment: Both heard it. So "it" would fine, right? Or both "it" and "that" be fine?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope You'd have to *know* that they heard it to say with certainty that "it" has been identified, so they must have given you some kind of verbal, or non-verbal acknowledgement. Maybe they said "what's *that*?" or perhaps they looked around trying to locate the sound, and they saw you doing the same, so you both know you're thinking about the ringing phone. Then sure, you could say "is it yours?"

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope If you haven't established what you're talking about, you could get: "Is it your phone?" - "sorry, is *what* my phone?". Saying "that" points to something specific, either the phone in front of you or the audible ringing. If you refer to "that ringing" and the other person hasn't heard it, then it prompts them to listen harder for it.

Comment: So if both my friend and know that it is defininetely a pnone ringing, but we dont't know if it is mine your his, then I can say "is it your phone"? Right?  If it is so. Could I use "that" even if both of us are sure that is the ringing if the phone? I am sorry, but these pronouns are very confusing.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope I think you'll find the dictionary definition of "that" very helpful too - "*used to identify a specific person or thing observed or heard by the speaker*". So even if you *have* heard or observed it, you should really use "that" unless you have met the criteria required in the dictionary definition of "it".